# JPA count query to count total result rows of a group by query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql

How to get total result rows below SQL query in JPQL:

```
select
        count(usertransa0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
    from
        user_transaction usertransa0_ cross 
    join
        merchant_master merchantma1_ 
    where
        usertransa0_.merchant_master=merchantma1_.id 
        and usertransa0_.status=0 
        and (
            usertransa0_.transaction_date between '2015-02-19' and '2015-02-20'
        ) 
    group by
        merchantma1_.full_name;
```

I have tried with:

```
SELECT COUNT(ut)
    FROM UserTransaction ut 
    WHERE ut.status = :stus AND ut.transactionDate between :frm AND :toDt"
    GROUP BY ut.merchantMaster.fullName
```

But it returns only first rows count, How can get total rows count?

EDIT:

My entity looks like:

```
public class UserTransaction extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private UserInfo info;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private MerchantMaster merchantMaster;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private PaymentMaster paymentMaster;

    @Column(name = "AMOUNT")
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_DATE")
    private Date transactionDate;

    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private Integer status;

    private String userTransactionID;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private UserTransactionRequest trRequest;

    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private UserTransactionResponse trResponse;

    //getters & setters
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between UserTransaction and MerchantMaster, `@OneToMany`?. Could you post your Entities code?

Comment: @DavidSN no, `@OneToOne` relationship

Comment: The SQL generated for any JPQL query will be shown in the log, so you can work out what is needed

Comment: What do you want to get as a result? If you want to get the total count of UserTransaction, you can remove the `group by` from your JPQL query. At this moment your query returns the count of UserTransaction for each MerchantMaster name

Comment: @DavidSN i want total count of each MerchantMaster name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query will return an array of Long. Each Long is the count of `UserTransaction` for a given MerchantMaster name.

if you have your query in a NamedQuery, you can use (if not, you can use the `creatyQuery()` method and use your JPQL query String):

```
TypedQuery<Long> query = em.createNamedQuery("UserTransaction.MyQuery", Long.class);
/* The list have the count of User Transaction grouped by Merchant name */
List<Long> userTransactionsPerMerchantName = query.getResultList();
```

You probably will also need the Merchant name, you can add the merchant name to your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(ut), ut.merchantMaster.fullName
FROM UserTransaction ut 
WHERE ut.status = :stus AND ut.transactionDate between :frm AND :toDt"
GROUP BY ut.merchantMaster.fullName
```

Now, the query will return an array of objects, the first object is the count, and the second is the name. You also need to modify the code to get the results:

```
TypedQuery<Object[]> query = em.createNamedQuery("UserTransaction.MyQuery", Object[].class);
List<Object []> results = query.getResultList();
for (Object [] row : results) {
    Long count = (Long) row[0];
    String name = (String) row[1];
}
```

Comment: +1 for the answer, but i need result in pagination where i have to find total no of results returned by group by function.

Comment: @Rembo I am not sure If this is what you mean, but if you want the total count of groups. You can use `query.getResultList().size()`